# How to hide “Chrome is being controlled by automated software” infobar within Chrome v77?

Tags: google-chrome, go, automation

How to hide “Chrome is being controlled by automated software” infobar within Chrome v77?
I used with `chromedp` a `disable-infobars` but that does not work.

```
opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
        chromedp.DisableGPU,
        chromedp.Flag("headless", false),
        chromedp.Flag("disable-infobars", true),
    )
```

Comment: I don't think you can, for security reasons (in the event someone tries to take over Chrome for malicious reasons).

Comment: @Adrian but that is possible, as I know, for Selenium Web Driver - there are a lot of threads with this issue